# Running ASP site with SQL Server 6.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

I have a classic ASP website. When I run the site locally on a Windows 2008 R2 server, it works perfectly. When I connect to the site from another machine and try to serve the page through iis 7.5, it fails with this error:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80004005'

The line in the asp that it is failing on is:

```
Set conSQL6 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conSQL6.Open strConSQL6
```

When I run this same application on a Win 2003 server there are no problems, both locally on the server and remotely.

Any ideas on how to make this work, a full re-write is not an option :)

Comment: Are you seriously using sql server 6.5??? You are LONG overdue for a complete rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PRB: Troubleshooting Error 80004005 "Login Failed" in ASP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306586)

> **Cause**
>
> There are two reasons why this error may occur:
>
> - Integrated security is turned on in the SQL Enterprise Manager, and the Microsoft Windows NT account that is being used has not been mapped to a SQL account.
> - The User ID in the connection string is invalid or blank.
>
> **RESOLUTION**
>
> To resolve this problem, ensure that the following conditions are met:
>
> - The Windows NT account is mapped to a SQL account.
> - The User ID in the connection string is valid and is not blank.
> - Set standard security in SQL Server Enterprise Manager. To implement SQL  Server standard security, follow these steps:
>
>   1. From SQL Enterprise Manager, right-click the SQL Server name that appears in the Server Manager window, and then click Properties. (For SQL Server version 6.5 click Configure).
>   2. Click Security Options, and then click Standard and Windows. (For SQL Server version 6.5 click Standard).
> - The Password Synchronization option is turned off for that project if you are running under Microsoft Internet Information Server (IIS) 4.0.